# Error registering in blender python

Tags: python

[image]

for some reasons I get this error while registering, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the add-on "rain".

It needs to register each class in classes. Like this:

```
from bpy.utils import register_class
for cls in classes:
    register_class(cls)
```

and unregister like this:

```
from bpy.utils import unregister_class
for cls in classes:
    unregister_class(cls)
```

Comment: Thanks you it did work!

Comment: Can you accept the answer as a solution?